# Triangle-Triangle Intersection Code

Tags: c++, collision-detection, intersection

Does anyone have experience implementing this [triangle-triangle intersection code](http://webee.technion.ac.il/cgm/Computer-Graphics-Multimedia/Software/TriangleIntersection/code.cpp) that I found online? I don't understand it. I made a post on Stack Overflow about this and got the advice that:

> From the sample code it seems like what it mean by an edge is the vector from the originating vertex to the end vertex. In the case of a triangle with three vertices C1, C2, C3, the two >input edges would be P1 = C2-C1, P2=C3-C1

I tried feeding it my triangles like that, but ended up with a pretty wildly inaccurate false positive:

```
Triangle* triangle1 = new Triangle(glm::vec3(-0.323523998f, 1.68264794f, -1.20740700f),
        glm::vec3(-0.478354007f, 1.68264794f, -1.15484905f),
        glm::vec3(-0.465537012f, 1.80764794f, -1.12390494f));
Triangle* triangle2 = new Triangle(glm::vec3(1.00000000f, -0.682647943f, -0.999998987f),
        glm::vec3(1.00000000f, -2.68264794f, -1.00000000f),
        glm::vec3(-1.00000000f, -0.682647943f, -1.00000000f));
collisionDetector.checkForCollision(triangle1, triangle2)
```

returned true, with the collisionDetector being a wrapper for this function and checkForCollision defined as:

```
bool TriangleTriangleCollision::checkForCollision(Triangle* triangle1, Triangle* triangle2)
{
    return checkForCollision(triangle1->_vertex0, triangle1->_vertex1, triangle1->_vertex2, 
        triangle2->_vertex0, triangle2->_vertex1, triangle2->_vertex2);
}

bool TriangleTriangleCollision::checkForCollision(glm::vec3 t1vert0, glm::vec3 t1vert1, 
    glm::vec3 t1vert2, glm::vec3 t2vert0, glm::vec3 t2vert1, glm::vec3 t2vert2)
{
    double C1[3], P1[3], P2[3], D1[3], Q1[3], Q2[3];

    glmVecToArray(t1vert0, C1);
    glmVecToArray(t1vert1 - t1vert0, P1);
    glmVecToArray(t1vert2 - t1vert0, P2);

    glmVecToArray(t2vert0, D1);
    glmVecToArray(t2vert1 - t2vert0, Q1);
    glmVecToArray(t2vert2 - t2vert0, Q1);

    return (tr_tri_intersect3D(C1, P1, P2, D1, Q1, Q2) > 0);
}

void TriangleTriangleCollision::glmVecToArray(const glm::vec3 vector, double v[3])
{
    v[0] = vector.x;
    v[1] = vector.y;
    v[2] = vector.z;
}
```

unless I am wrong, these two triangles are not at all near each other.

If not, does anyone have any reliable triangle-triangle intersection code? I'm on a time crunch working on a collision detection system for a school project and spent all my time implementing the code to weed out triangle-triangle collision detection so I'm going to have to use some code from someone else and just cite it in my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look at a number of implementations that are all based off of this paper:

http://home.arcor.de/philippe.guigue/triangle_triangle_intersection.htm

Here is one that I extracted and ran with your numbers - it returns no collision. You can look at main() to see the invocation with your test numbers. I have not done any more analysis than that. Good luck.

From https://github.com/benardp/contours/blob/master/freestyle/view_map/triangle_triangle_intersection.c

```
/*              
 *  Triangle-Triangle Overlap Test Routines             
 *  July, 2002                                                          
 *  Updated December 2003                                                
 *                                                                       
 *  This file contains C implementation of algorithms for                
 *  performing two and three-dimensional triangle-triangle intersection test 
 *  The algorithms and underlying theory are described in                    
 *                                                                           
 * "Fast and Robust Triangle-Triangle Overlap Test 
 *  Using Orientation Predicates"  P. Guigue - O. Devillers
 *                                                 
 *  Journal of Graphics Tools, 8(1), 2003                                    
 *                                                                           
 *  Several geometric predicates are defined.  Their parameters are all      
 *  points.  Each point is an array of two or three real precision         
 *  floating point numbers. The geometric predicates implemented in          
 *  this file are:                                                            
 *                                                                           
 *    int tri_tri_overlap_test_3d(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2)                         
 *    int tri_tri_overlap_test_2d(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2)                         
 *                                                                           
 *    int tri_tri_intersection_test_3d(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2,
 *                                     coplanar,source,target)               
 *                                                                           
 *       is a version that computes the segment of intersection when            
 *       the triangles overlap (and are not coplanar)                        
 *                                                                           
 *    each function returns 1 if the triangles (including their              
 *    boundary) intersect, otherwise 0                                       
 *                                                                           
 *                                                                           
 *  Other information are available from the Web page                        
 *  http:<i>//www.acm.org/jgt/papers/GuigueDevillers03/                         
 *                                                                           
 */

// modified by Aaron to better detect coplanarity

typedef float real;

#define ZERO_TEST(x)  (x == 0)
//#define ZERO_TEST(x)  ((x) > -0.001 && (x) < .001)

#include "stdio.h"

/* function prototype */

int tri_tri_overlap_test_3d(real p1[3], real q1[3], real r1[3], 
                            real p2[3], real q2[3], real r2[3]);


int coplanar_tri_tri3d(real  p1[3], real  q1[3], real  r1[3],
                       real  p2[3], real  q2[3], real  r2[3],
                       real  N1[3], real  N2[3]);


int tri_tri_overlap_test_2d(real p1[2], real q1[2], real r1[2], 
                            real p2[2], real q2[2], real r2[2]);


int tri_tri_intersection_test_3d(real p1[3], real q1[3], real r1[3], 
                                 real p2[3], real q2[3], real r2[3],
                                 int * coplanar, 
                                 real source[3],real target[3]);

/* coplanar returns whether the triangles are coplanar  
 *  source and target are the endpoints of the segment of 
 *  intersection if it exists) 
 */


/* some 3D macros */

#define CROSS(dest,v1,v2)                       \
dest[0]=v1[1]*v2[2]-v1[2]*v2[1]; \
dest[1]=v1[2]*v2[0]-v1[0]*v2[2]; \
dest[2]=v1[0]*v2[1]-v1[1]*v2[0];

#define DOT(v1,v2) (v1[0]*v2[0]+v1[1]*v2[1]+v1[2]*v2[2])

#define SUB(dest,v1,v2) dest[0]=v1[0]-v2[0]; \
dest[1]=v1[1]-v2[1]; \
dest[2]=v1[2]-v2[2]; 

#define SCALAR(dest,alpha,v) dest[0] = alpha * v[0]; \
dest[1] = alpha * v[1]; \
dest[2] = alpha * v[2];

#define CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2) {\
SUB(v1,p2,q1)\
SUB(v2,p1,q1)\
CROSS(N1,v1,v2)\
SUB(v1,q2,q1)\
if (DOT(v1,N1) > 0.0f) return 0;\
SUB(v1,p2,p1)\
SUB(v2,r1,p1)\
CROSS(N1,v1,v2)\
SUB(v1,r2,p1) \
if (DOT(v1,N1) > 0.0f) return 0;\
else return 1; }



/* Permutation in a canonical form of T2's vertices */

#define TRI_TRI_3D(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2) { \
if (dp2 > 0.0f) { \
if (dq2 > 0.0f) CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,r1,q1,r2,p2,q2) \
else if (dr2 > 0.0f) CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,r1,q1,q2,r2,p2)\
else CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2) }\
else if (dp2 < 0.0f) { \
if (dq2 < 0.0f) CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,q1,r1,r2,p2,q2)\
else if (dr2 < 0.0f) CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,q1,r1,q2,r2,p2)\
else CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,r1,q1,p2,q2,r2)\
} else { \
if (dq2 < 0.0f) { \
if (dr2 >= 0.0f)  CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,r1,q1,q2,r2,p2)\
else CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2)\
} \
else if (dq2 > 0.0f) { \
if (dr2 > 0.0f) CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,r1,q1,p2,q2,r2)\
else  CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,q1,r1,q2,r2,p2)\
} \
else  { \
if (dr2 > 0.0f) CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,q1,r1,r2,p2,q2)\
else if (dr2 < 0.0f) CHECK_MIN_MAX(p1,r1,q1,r2,p2,q2)\
else return coplanar_tri_tri3d(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2,N1,N2);\
}}}



/*
 *
 *  Three-dimensional Triangle-Triangle Overlap Test
 *
 */


int tri_tri_overlap_test_3d(real p1[3], real q1[3], real r1[3], 

                            real p2[3], real q2[3], real r2[3])
{
    real dp1, dq1, dr1, dp2, dq2, dr2;
    real v1[3], v2[3];
    real N1[3], N2[3]; 

    /* Compute distance signs  of p1, q1 and r1 to the plane of
     triangle(p2,q2,r2) */


    SUB(v1,p2,r2)
    SUB(v2,q2,r2)
    CROSS(N2,v1,v2)

    SUB(v1,p1,r2)
    dp1 = DOT(v1,N2);
    SUB(v1,q1,r2)
    dq1 = DOT(v1,N2);
    SUB(v1,r1,r2)
    dr1 = DOT(v1,N2);

    if (((dp1 * dq1) > 0.0f) && ((dp1 * dr1) > 0.0f))  return 0; 

    /* Compute distance signs  of p2, q2 and r2 to the plane of
     triangle(p1,q1,r1) */


    SUB(v1,q1,p1)
    SUB(v2,r1,p1)
    CROSS(N1,v1,v2)

    SUB(v1,p2,r1)
    dp2 = DOT(v1,N1);
    SUB(v1,q2,r1)
    dq2 = DOT(v1,N1);
    SUB(v1,r2,r1)
    dr2 = DOT(v1,N1);

    if (((dp2 * dq2) > 0.0f) && ((dp2 * dr2) > 0.0f)) return 0;

    /* Permutation in a canonical form of T1's vertices */




    if (dp1 > 0.0f) {
        if (dq1 > 0.0f) TRI_TRI_3D(r1,p1,q1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)
            else if (dr1 > 0.0f) TRI_TRI_3D(q1,r1,p1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)  
                else TRI_TRI_3D(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                    } else if (dp1 < 0.0f) {
                        if (dq1 < 0.0f) TRI_TRI_3D(r1,p1,q1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                            else if (dr1 < 0.0f) TRI_TRI_3D(q1,r1,p1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                                else TRI_TRI_3D(p1,q1,r1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)
                                    } else {
                                        if (dq1 < 0.0f) {
                                            if (dr1 >= 0.0f) TRI_TRI_3D(q1,r1,p1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)
                                                else TRI_TRI_3D(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                                                    }
                                        else if (dq1 > 0.0f) {
                                            if (dr1 > 0.0f) TRI_TRI_3D(p1,q1,r1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)
                                                else TRI_TRI_3D(q1,r1,p1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                                                    }
                                        else  {
                                            if (dr1 > 0.0f) TRI_TRI_3D(r1,p1,q1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                                                else if (dr1 < 0.0f) TRI_TRI_3D(r1,p1,q1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)
                                                    else return coplanar_tri_tri3d(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2,N1,N2);
                                        }
                                    }
};



int coplanar_tri_tri3d(real p1[3], real q1[3], real r1[3],
                       real p2[3], real q2[3], real r2[3],
                       real normal_1[3], real normal_2[3]){

    real P1[2],Q1[2],R1[2];
    real P2[2],Q2[2],R2[2];

    real n_x, n_y, n_z;

    n_x = ((normal_1[0]<0)?-normal_1[0]:normal_1[0]);
    n_y = ((normal_1[1]<0)?-normal_1[1]:normal_1[1]);
    n_z = ((normal_1[2]<0)?-normal_1[2]:normal_1[2]);


    /* Projection of the triangles in 3D onto 2D such that the area of
     the projection is maximized. */


    if (( n_x > n_z ) && ( n_x >= n_y )) {
        // Project onto plane YZ

        P1[0] = q1[2]; P1[1] = q1[1];
        Q1[0] = p1[2]; Q1[1] = p1[1];
        R1[0] = r1[2]; R1[1] = r1[1]; 

        P2[0] = q2[2]; P2[1] = q2[1];
        Q2[0] = p2[2]; Q2[1] = p2[1];
        R2[0] = r2[2]; R2[1] = r2[1]; 

    } else if (( n_y > n_z ) && ( n_y >= n_x )) {
        // Project onto plane XZ

        P1[0] = q1[0]; P1[1] = q1[2];
        Q1[0] = p1[0]; Q1[1] = p1[2];
        R1[0] = r1[0]; R1[1] = r1[2]; 

        P2[0] = q2[0]; P2[1] = q2[2];
        Q2[0] = p2[0]; Q2[1] = p2[2];
        R2[0] = r2[0]; R2[1] = r2[2]; 

    } else {
        // Project onto plane XY

        P1[0] = p1[0]; P1[1] = p1[1]; 
        Q1[0] = q1[0]; Q1[1] = q1[1]; 
        R1[0] = r1[0]; R1[1] = r1[1]; 

        P2[0] = p2[0]; P2[1] = p2[1]; 
        Q2[0] = q2[0]; Q2[1] = q2[1]; 
        R2[0] = r2[0]; R2[1] = r2[1]; 
    }

    return tri_tri_overlap_test_2d(P1,Q1,R1,P2,Q2,R2);

};



/*
 *                                                                
 *  Three-dimensional Triangle-Triangle Intersection              
 *
 */

/*
 This macro is called when the triangles surely intersect
 It constructs the segment of intersection of the two triangles
 if they are not coplanar.
 */

#define CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2) { \
SUB(v1,q1,p1) \
SUB(v2,r2,p1) \
CROSS(N,v1,v2) \
SUB(v,p2,p1) \
if (DOT(v,N) > 0.0f) {\
SUB(v1,r1,p1) \
CROSS(N,v1,v2) \
if (DOT(v,N) <= 0.0f) { \
SUB(v2,q2,p1) \
CROSS(N,v1,v2) \
if (DOT(v,N) > 0.0f) { \
SUB(v1,p1,p2) \
SUB(v2,p1,r1) \
alpha = DOT(v1,N2) / DOT(v2,N2); \
SCALAR(v1,alpha,v2) \
SUB(source,p1,v1) \
SUB(v1,p2,p1) \
SUB(v2,p2,r2) \
alpha = DOT(v1,N1) / DOT(v2,N1); \
SCALAR(v1,alpha,v2) \
SUB(target,p2,v1) \
return 1; \
} else { \
SUB(v1,p2,p1) \
SUB(v2,p2,q2) \
alpha = DOT(v1,N1) / DOT(v2,N1); \
SCALAR(v1,alpha,v2) \
SUB(source,p2,v1) \
SUB(v1,p2,p1) \
SUB(v2,p2,r2) \
alpha = DOT(v1,N1) / DOT(v2,N1); \
SCALAR(v1,alpha,v2) \
SUB(target,p2,v1) \
return 1; \
} \
} else { \
return 0; \
} \
} else { \
SUB(v2,q2,p1) \
CROSS(N,v1,v2) \
if (DOT(v,N) < 0.0f) { \
return 0; \
} else { \
SUB(v1,r1,p1) \
CROSS(N,v1,v2) \
if (DOT(v,N) >= 0.0f) { \
SUB(v1,p1,p2) \
SUB(v2,p1,r1) \
alpha = DOT(v1,N2) / DOT(v2,N2); \
SCALAR(v1,alpha,v2) \
SUB(source,p1,v1) \
SUB(v1,p1,p2) \
SUB(v2,p1,q1) \
alpha = DOT(v1,N2) / DOT(v2,N2); \
SCALAR(v1,alpha,v2) \
SUB(target,p1,v1) \
return 1; \
} else { \
SUB(v1,p2,p1) \
SUB(v2,p2,q2) \
alpha = DOT(v1,N1) / DOT(v2,N1); \
SCALAR(v1,alpha,v2) \
SUB(source,p2,v1) \
SUB(v1,p1,p2) \
SUB(v2,p1,q1) \
alpha = DOT(v1,N2) / DOT(v2,N2); \
SCALAR(v1,alpha,v2) \
SUB(target,p1,v1) \
return 1; \
}}}} 



#define TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2) { \
if (dp2 > 0.0f) { \
if (dq2 > 0.0f) CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,r1,q1,r2,p2,q2) \
else if (dr2 > 0.0f) CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,r1,q1,q2,r2,p2)\
else CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2) }\
else if (dp2 < 0.0f) { \
if (dq2 < 0.0f) CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,q1,r1,r2,p2,q2)\
else if (dr2 < 0.0f) CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,q1,r1,q2,r2,p2)\
else CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,r1,q1,p2,q2,r2)\
} else { \
if (dq2 < 0.0f) { \
if (dr2 >= 0.0f)  CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,r1,q1,q2,r2,p2)\
else CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2)\
} \
else if (dq2 > 0.0f) { \
if (dr2 > 0.0f) CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,r1,q1,p2,q2,r2)\
else  CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,q1,r1,q2,r2,p2)\
} \
else  { \
if (dr2 > 0.0f) CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,q1,r1,r2,p2,q2)\
else if (dr2 < 0.0f) CONSTRUCT_INTERSECTION(p1,r1,q1,r2,p2,q2)\
else { \
*coplanar = 1; \
return coplanar_tri_tri3d(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2,N1,N2);\
} \
}} }


/*
 The following version computes the segment of intersection of the
 two triangles if it exists. 
 coplanar returns whether the triangles are coplanar
 source and target are the endpoints of the line segment of intersection 
 */

int tri_tri_intersection_test_3d(real p1[3], real q1[3], real r1[3], 
                                 real p2[3], real q2[3], real r2[3],
                                 int * coplanar, 
                                 real source[3], real target[3] )

{
    real dp1, dq1, dr1, dp2, dq2, dr2;
    real v1[3], v2[3], v[3];
    real N1[3], N2[3], N[3];
    real alpha;

    // Compute distance signs  of p1, q1 and r1 
    // to the plane of triangle(p2,q2,r2)


    SUB(v1,p2,r2)
    SUB(v2,q2,r2)
    CROSS(N2,v1,v2)

    SUB(v1,p1,r2)
    dp1 = DOT(v1,N2);
    SUB(v1,q1,r2)
    dq1 = DOT(v1,N2);
    SUB(v1,r1,r2)
    dr1 = DOT(v1,N2);

    if (((dp1 * dq1) > 0.0f) && ((dp1 * dr1) > 0.0f))  return 0; 

    // Compute distance signs  of p2, q2 and r2 
    // to the plane of triangle(p1,q1,r1)


    SUB(v1,q1,p1)
    SUB(v2,r1,p1)
    CROSS(N1,v1,v2)

    SUB(v1,p2,r1)
    dp2 = DOT(v1,N1);
    SUB(v1,q2,r1)
    dq2 = DOT(v1,N1);
    SUB(v1,r2,r1)
    dr2 = DOT(v1,N1);

    if (((dp2 * dq2) > 0.0f) && ((dp2 * dr2) > 0.0f)) return 0;

    // Permutation in a canonical form of T1's vertices


    //  printf("d1 = [%f %f %f], d2 = [%f %f %f]\n", dp1, dq1, dr1, dp2, dq2, dr2);
    /*
     // added by Aaron
     if (ZERO_TEST(dp1) || ZERO_TEST(dq1) ||ZERO_TEST(dr1) ||ZERO_TEST(dp2) ||ZERO_TEST(dq2) ||ZERO_TEST(dr2))
     {
     coplanar = 1;
     return 0;
     }
     */


    if (dp1 > 0.0f) {
        if (dq1 > 0.0f) TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(r1,p1,q1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)
            else if (dr1 > 0.0f) TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(q1,r1,p1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)

                else TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                    } else if (dp1 < 0.0f) {
                        if (dq1 < 0.0f) TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(r1,p1,q1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                            else if (dr1 < 0.0f) TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(q1,r1,p1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                                else TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(p1,q1,r1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)
                                    } else {
                                        if (dq1 < 0.0f) {
                                            if (dr1 >= 0.0f) TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(q1,r1,p1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)
                                                else TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                                                    }
                                        else if (dq1 > 0.0f) {
                                            if (dr1 > 0.0f) TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(p1,q1,r1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)
                                                else TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(q1,r1,p1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                                                    }
                                        else  {
                                            if (dr1 > 0.0f) TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(r1,p1,q1,p2,q2,r2,dp2,dq2,dr2)
                                                else if (dr1 < 0.0f) TRI_TRI_INTER_3D(r1,p1,q1,p2,r2,q2,dp2,dr2,dq2)
                                                    else {
                                                        // triangles are co-planar

                                                        *coplanar = 1;
                                                        return coplanar_tri_tri3d(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2,N1,N2);
                                                    }
                                        }
                                    }
};





/*
 *
 *  Two dimensional Triangle-Triangle Overlap Test    
 *
 */


/* some 2D macros */

#define ORIENT_2D(a, b, c)  ((a[0]-c[0])*(b[1]-c[1])-(a[1]-c[1])*(b[0]-c[0]))


#define INTERSECTION_TEST_VERTEXA(P1, Q1, R1, P2, Q2, R2) {\
if (ORIENT_2D(R2,P2,Q1) >= 0.0f)\
if (ORIENT_2D(R2,Q2,Q1) <= 0.0f)\
if (ORIENT_2D(P1,P2,Q1) > 0.0f) {\
if (ORIENT_2D(P1,Q2,Q1) <= 0.0f) return 1; \
else return 0;} else {\
if (ORIENT_2D(P1,P2,R1) >= 0.0f)\
if (ORIENT_2D(Q1,R1,P2) >= 0.0f) return 1; \
else return 0;\
else return 0;}\
else \
if (ORIENT_2D(P1,Q2,Q1) <= 0.0f)\
if (ORIENT_2D(R2,Q2,R1) <= 0.0f)\
if (ORIENT_2D(Q1,R1,Q2) >= 0.0f) return 1; \
else return 0;\
else return 0;\
else return 0;\
else\
if (ORIENT_2D(R2,P2,R1) >= 0.0f) \
if (ORIENT_2D(Q1,R1,R2) >= 0.0f)\
if (ORIENT_2D(P1,P2,R1) >= 0.0f) return 1;\
else return 0;\
else \
if (ORIENT_2D(Q1,R1,Q2) >= 0.0f) {\
if (ORIENT_2D(R2,R1,Q2) >= 0.0f) return 1; \
else return 0; }\
else return 0; \
else  return 0; \
};

#define INTERSECTION_TEST_VERTEX(P1, Q1, R1, P2, Q2, R2) {\
  if (ORIENT_2D(R2,P2,Q1) >= 0.0f)\
    if (ORIENT_2D(R2,Q2,Q1) <= 0.0f)\
      if (ORIENT_2D(P1,P2,Q1) > 0.0f) {\
        if (ORIENT_2D(P1,Q2,Q1) <= 0.0f) return 1; \
        else return 0;} else {\
        if (ORIENT_2D(P1,P2,R1) >= 0.0f)\
          if (ORIENT_2D(Q1,R1,P2) >= 0.0f) return 1; \
          else return 0;\
        else return 0;}\
    else \
      if (ORIENT_2D(P1,Q2,Q1) <= 0.0f)\
        if (ORIENT_2D(R2,Q2,R1) <= 0.0f)\
          if (ORIENT_2D(Q1,R1,Q2) >= 0.0f) return 1; \
          else return 0;\
        else return 0;\
      else return 0;\
  else\
    if (ORIENT_2D(R2,P2,R1) >= 0.0f) \
      if (ORIENT_2D(Q1,R1,R2) >= 0.0f)\
        if (ORIENT_2D(P1,P2,R1) >= 0.0f) return 1;\
        else return 0;\
      else \
        if (ORIENT_2D(Q1,R1,Q2) >= 0.0f) {\
          if (ORIENT_2D(R2,R1,Q2) >= 0.0f) return 1; \
          else return 0; }\
        else return 0; \
    else  return 0; \
 };


#define INTERSECTION_TEST_EDGE(P1, Q1, R1, P2, Q2, R2) { \
if (ORIENT_2D(R2,P2,Q1) >= 0.0f) {\
if (ORIENT_2D(P1,P2,Q1) >= 0.0f) { \
if (ORIENT_2D(P1,Q1,R2) >= 0.0f) return 1; \
else return 0;} else { \
if (ORIENT_2D(Q1,R1,P2) >= 0.0f){ \
if (ORIENT_2D(R1,P1,P2) >= 0.0f) return 1; else return 0;} \
else return 0; } \
} else {\
if (ORIENT_2D(R2,P2,R1) >= 0.0f) {\
if (ORIENT_2D(P1,P2,R1) >= 0.0f) {\
if (ORIENT_2D(P1,R1,R2) >= 0.0f) return 1;  \
else {\
if (ORIENT_2D(Q1,R1,R2) >= 0.0f) return 1; else return 0;}}\
else  return 0; }\
else return 0; }}



int ccw_tri_tri_intersection_2d(real p1[2], real q1[2], real r1[2], 
                                real p2[2], real q2[2], real r2[2]) {
    if ( ORIENT_2D(p2,q2,p1) >= 0.0f ) {
        if ( ORIENT_2D(q2,r2,p1) >= 0.0f ) {
            if ( ORIENT_2D(r2,p2,p1) >= 0.0f ) return 1;
            else INTERSECTION_TEST_EDGE(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2)
                } else {  
                    if ( ORIENT_2D(r2,p2,p1) >= 0.0f ) 
                        INTERSECTION_TEST_EDGE(p1,q1,r1,r2,p2,q2)
                        else INTERSECTION_TEST_VERTEX(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2)}}
    else {
        if ( ORIENT_2D(q2,r2,p1) >= 0.0f ) {
            if ( ORIENT_2D(r2,p2,p1) >= 0.0f ) 
                INTERSECTION_TEST_EDGE(p1,q1,r1,q2,r2,p2)
                else  INTERSECTION_TEST_VERTEX(p1,q1,r1,q2,r2,p2)}
        else INTERSECTION_TEST_VERTEX(p1,q1,r1,r2,p2,q2)}
};


int tri_tri_overlap_test_2d(real p1[2], real q1[2], real r1[2], 
                            real p2[2], real q2[2], real r2[2]) {
    if ( ORIENT_2D(p1,q1,r1) < 0.0f )
        if ( ORIENT_2D(p2,q2,r2) < 0.0f )
            return ccw_tri_tri_intersection_2d(p1,r1,q1,p2,r2,q2);
        else
            return ccw_tri_tri_intersection_2d(p1,r1,q1,p2,q2,r2);
        else
            if ( ORIENT_2D(p2,q2,r2) < 0.0f )
                return ccw_tri_tri_intersection_2d(p1,q1,r1,p2,r2,q2);
            else
                return ccw_tri_tri_intersection_2d(p1,q1,r1,p2,q2,r2);

};


int main()
{
    float p1[3] = { -0.323523998f, 1.68264794f, -1.20740700f };
    float p2[3] = { -0.478354007f, 1.68264794f, -1.15484905f };
    float p3[3] = { -0.465537012f, 1.80764794f, -1.12390494f };

    float q1[3] = { 1.00000000f, -0.682647943f, -0.999998987f };
    float q2[3] = { 1.00000000f, -2.68264794f, -1.00000000f };
    float q3[3] = { -1.00000000f, -0.682647943f, -1.00000000f };

    int i = tri_tri_overlap_test_3d( p1, p2, p3, q1, q2, q3 );
    printf( "Result = %d\n", i );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sweeeet. A thousand thanks. If I'm reading it correctly, all I have to do is input the three vertices as a float[3] into tri_tri_overlap_test_3d()?

Comment: I got it implemented in my code and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.